# Realm and RxSwift: A field change listener updating a field in the same object fails

Tags: ios, swift, realm, rx-swift

I have a way to work around this, but would like to know generally if this is just an inappropriate pattern for Realm and RxSwift or if it reflects a bug in the underlying framework interaction. Here's what I'm doing. I have set up a change listener on one Realm entity (call that entity A; this is only ever a single instance or record of this type of Realm object) looking for changes, except for a few special fields in entity A. I use:

```
extension Observable where Element: Object {
    /// Observe changes to object *except* for specific fields.
    static func from(object: Element, emitInitialValue: Bool = true,
                     exceptForProperties: [String]) -> Observable<Element> {
        return Observable<Element>.create { observer in
            if emitInitialValue {
                observer.onNext(object)
            }

            let token = object.observe { change in
                switch change {
                case .change(let changedProperties):
                    if changedProperties.contains(where: {
                        return exceptForProperties.contains($0.name)
                    }) {
                        // if change property is an excepted one, just return
                        return
                    }
                    observer.onNext(object)
                case .deleted:
                    observer.onError(RxRealmError.objectDeleted)
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
            }

            return Disposables.create {
                token.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I detect a change in one of the non-special fields in entity A, I update the special fields in entity A (e.g., this includes a "dirty" flag indicating I need to upload the Realm entity).

What I'm finding is that when I follow this sequence:
1) Change one of the non-special fields in the Realm entity A 
2) Do a Realm write with some other Realm entity, entity B (a different type of Realm object)
3) At exactly the point where that Realm write in 2) starts, that triggers the change listener for entity A. And tries do another (nested) Realm write, which of course fails with a Realm exception.

Is this just an inappropriate pattern to use (having a field change listener update that same entity) or is something else going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's an inappropriate pattern. "Changes in A cause A to change" is inherently circular and you want to strive for a unidirectional data flow.

You say in your question "When I detect a change in one of the non-special fields in entity A..." and that raises the question, what changed the non-special field and while it was changing the non-special field, why didn't it *also* make the other necessary changes?

There are specific reasons to change any particular field in A. For each field, you should outline what those reasons are, and *they* should be doing the changing.

Comment: Thanks. `you want to strive for a unidirectional data flow`-- is this general purpose reasoning or something to do with Realm or Rx more specifically? And I'm nodding on the second part. That's how I worked around this.

Comment: A little more specifically, it'd be nice to know what differs in Realm/RxSwift technically between changes in A causing A to change versus changes in A causing B to change? I'm not asking a style question or general purpose software engineering question here. While I can avoid this pattern on the basis of it being an inappropriate pattern, I'd still like to know why this is pattern is failing.